# Trying to build a list using recursion. Value in global list doesn't change

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, recursion, scope

So I'm doing a problem, and I use a recursive solution. For simplicity, let's say the problem is that I need to find all anagrams of a given string. (The problem is much complicated, but this is enough to illustrate what I'm doing).

I am using recursion to do this.

```
all_anagrams = []

def main():
    ...
    ...
    get_anagrams() # calls a method that appends anagrams to list all_anagrams
    print all_anagrams
```

and the method `get_anagrams` is:

```
def get_anagrams(user_word, anagram, words, inventory):
'''
Finds all anagrams for the given user_word.
'''
    if len(inventory) == 0:
        all_anagrams.append(anagram)
    else:
        for choice in words:
                if len(choice) <= len(inventory) and choice in inventory:
                anagram.append(choice)
                inventory.subtract(choice)
                get_anagrams(user_word, anagram, words, inventory)
                    anagram.pop()
                    inventory.add(choice)
```

`all_anagrams` is supposed to be a nested list, where each sub-list is composed of some words.

Now `get_anagrams` should change the global value of `all_anagrams` but it doesn't. In `main`, it prints `[[], [], [], [], [], []]`, but within the method it prints the correct list.

Consider this for example:

```
>>> a_list = []
>>> def change_list(some_list):
...     some_list.append(1)
...     some_list.append(2)
...     
>>> 
>>> change_list(a_list)
>>> a_list
[1, 2]
```

I've tried defining the list as a `global` list, or passing the list as a parameter since any changes to list made by callee should be reflected in the caller too. But nothing worked.

Why is it so? How do I fix it?

Comment: The fun way is to use `yield` and `yield from` instead of appending to a global list. Please use the fun way; it will probably also solve your problem.

Comment: The fun way (`yield from`) sadly doesn't work in py 2.7

Comment: Then `yield` in a loop. Also, `if len(inventory) == 0` can be `if inventory`.

Comment: @minitech You mean, `if not inventory:`?

Comment: @thefourtheye: Yes, or flip the blocks. (It looks better that way!)

Comment: I agree with  minitech though, yield (not from), works with Python 2.7, et is probably much better than recursion (which limited to a 1000 nesting levels by default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem is with the `append` and `pop`. When you do

```
all_anagrams.append(anagram)
```

You are adding the reference to `anagram` to `all_anagrams`. But, when the recursion unwinds, you are popping the values from `anagram`. Thats why empty lists are printed in `main`. The immediate fix would be like this

```
            if len(choice) <= len(inventory) and choice in inventory:
            inventory.subtract(choice)
            get_anagrams(user_word, anagram + [choice], words, inventory)
            inventory.add(choice)
```

And as e-satis suggested, please avoid using global variables and pass `all_anagrams` as one of the parameters.

Comment: +1. Also, pass `all_anagrams` as a parameter, don't use a global variable.  And returns it.

Comment: @e-satis Thanks :) Added a note to use `all_anagrams` as a parameter instead of using it as a global variable.